# Keep track of loop without a counter

Tags: haskell

Say, I got a list which length can be odd or even. Every iteration , I remove two items from the list. If there is one or no item at the end, I end the execution.

If I store (length list)/2 every loop, I will get e.g. [5,4,3...] for a list of length 10.

But what I want is [1,2,3,...] and I couldn't figure out a relationship between the list size and this sequence...

Is there a way to achieve this without having a variable storing the current count?

i.e. with `func :: [Int] -> [Int]` only

Comment: If all you want a sequence of `[1,2,3...]`, then you can have `n, n+1, ...` sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do this without changing the type signature of `func :: [Int] -> [Int]`: have `func` call a different function, which takes an extra argument that is the counter you were talking about:

```
func :: [Int] -> [Int]
func = go 0
  where go _ [] = []
        go _ [x] = []
        go n (a:b:xs) = n : a : b : go (succ n) xs

func [11,12..20]
[0,11,12,1,13,14,2,15,16,3,17,18,4,19,20]
```

If you are determined to do this without managing the counter variable yourself, you can do something more contorted, such as zipping your input list into 3-tuples `(a,b,n)`, where `a` and `b` are pairs of items from your input list and `n` comes from `[1,2..]`.

```
pairs :: [a] -> [(a,a)]
pairs [] = []
pairs [_] = []
pairs (a:b:xs) = (a,b) : pairs xs

func' :: [Int] -> [Int]
func' xs = concat $ zipWith (\n (a,b) -> [n,a,b]) [1,2..] $ pairs xs

func' [11,12..20]
[1,11,12,2,13,14,3,15,16,4,17,18,5,19,20]
```

This is quite a bit less readable in my opinion, and I would suggest you just do the easy, obvious thing in my first snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know I can do it by calling another function. But I am trying to think of something smart so that I don't have to...if thats possible.

Comment: @xcoder you almost certainly *can* (combining functions like `fix`, `maybe`, `fst`, `snd`, `uncons`, `zipWith`, etc.), but whyyyy?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's another solution:

```
func :: [a] -> [Int]
func (_:_:as) = 1 : map (+1) (func as)
func _ = []
```

I'm a bit unclear what you want the base cases to be, so I guessed you wanted `func [] = []` and `func [_] = []`.  Correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Working through your 10 element list example:

```
func ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'] = 
1 : map (+1) (func ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']) = 
1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (func ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'])) = 
1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (func ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j']))) = 
1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (func ['i', 'j'])))) = 
1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (func []))))) = 
1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) [])))) = 
1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (1 : [])))) = 
1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (1 : 2 : []))) = 
1 : map (+1) (1 : map (+1) (1 : 2 : 3 : [])) = 
1 : map (+1) (1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : [])) = 
1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : 5 : []) = 
[1,2,3,4,5]
```